# How to avoid this error?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

How to avoid this error?

`Essai48photo.MainPage.MainPage()` must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

```
namespace Essai48photo
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage();

        // Variables            
        private int savedCounter = 0; 
        PhotoCamera cam;  
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();    
     }
}
```

How can i get ride of this error?
I use Visual Studio 2012 for Windows phone.

Comment: `public MainPage(){}` you need {}

Comment: When the compiler tells you you must declare a body, you must declare a body. If you're having trouble understanding what that means, *that* is what you should be asking.

Comment: @hvd +1 that's a good point

Comment: already understand the body part. Just don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a body to your constructor, just as the error tells you to:

```
namespace Essai48photo
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
       // Constructor

       public MainPage()
       {
       }

       // Variables               

       private int savedCounter = 0; 

       PhotoCamera cam;  

       MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();  

   }
}
```

Comment: Already tryied those solution but, it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: `It doesn't solve my issue`...doesn't tell us much. What error do you get *now*? What does your code look like *now*?

Comment: public MainPage(){} Worked, thx a lot!!!